# How to return ASP as an ActionResult?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In my ASP.NET MVC project I have a requirement to return certain pages in a database-driven way, i.e. the ASP page code is stored in the database, I need to retrieve it and return that.

I tried doing this using a ContentResult, but the problem I'm finding is that all the special characters denoting server-side script are coming through literally and being displayed in the browser.

How do I return an ActionResult that behaves as an ASP page, not as content?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do that.  ASP (Active **Server** Pages) is meant to be interpreted by the web server and only on the server-side.  You'd have to write your own client-side ASP interpreter with something like JavaScript to be able to do what you want to do (who knows, maybe that already exists - I haven't looked).  But this sounds like a very, very bad idea.

Comment: Instead, you should return either pure HTML that can be injected via JavaScript, or return just pure data (see JsonResult) and bind it to your HTML containers via JavaScript.